# How can I update a label in controller (A) when deleting a table row in controller(B)?

Tags: ios, delegates

I have a view controller(A) with a label displaying the balance of some transactions.  within the view controller I have a container view that holds a table view controller (B)

The balance updates when i change view controllers (with Tab bar) but I want to make it so that if a row gets deleted in controller B the label in controller A updates.

I am just learning objective C and i am not very comfortable with delegates.  Here is the code that relates to what I am saying:

ControllerB header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol KTTransactionsTableViewControllerDelegate

-(void) updateLabelWithString:(NSString*)string;

@end

@interface KTTransactionsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *transactions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<KTTransactionsTableViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

Deleting rows in controller B:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [KTCoreDateHelper managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:(KTTransaction*)[self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        [self.transactions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        //update the balance display

        KTSummaryViewController *summaryVC = [[KTSummaryViewController alloc]init];
        NSString* remainingBalance = [summaryVC calculateBalance];
        [self.delegate updateLabelWithString:remainingBalance];

    }
}
```

Controller A header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KTTransactionsTableViewController.h"

@interface KTSummaryViewController : UIViewController <KTTransactionsTableViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *remainingBalance;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *dateView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *categoryView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;



- (IBAction)segmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

-(NSString*)calculateBalance;


@end
```

Controller A implementation:

```
#import "KTSummaryViewController.h"
#import "KTCategory.h"
#import "KTCoreDateHelper.h"
#import "KTTransaction.h"

@interface KTSummaryViewController ()

@end

@implementation KTSummaryViewController

@synthesize dateView,categoryView,remainingBalance;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    remainingBalance.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateLabelWithString:[self calculateBalance]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSString*) calculateBalance
{
    //Get all the Income transactions
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [KTCoreDateHelper managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"KTTransaction"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];


    // Create an expression for the key path.
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];

    // Create an expression to represent the sum of marks
    NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                                            arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"amountSum"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:maxExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

    // Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *amountResult = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", amountResult);

    NSNumber *sumOfAmounts = [[amountResult objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"amountSum"];

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSString *sumCurrency = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:sumOfAmounts];

    NSLog(@"%@",sumCurrency);


    return sumCurrency;
}

-(void)updateLabelWithString:(NSString *)string{
    remainingBalance.text = string;

}
```

Any help with understanding what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set controller A as the delegate of controller B. Since B is in a container view of controller A, prepareForSegue will be called when these controllers are instantiated. You can set controller A as the delegate there (this code is in controller A),

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Embed"]) {
        KTTransactionsTableViewController *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

If you only have one segue from this controller, you can omit the if statement. If you use that clause, be sure you give the segue the same identifier in IB as you pass here.

Comment: Good answer. Also, OP: you should get comfortable with delegates. For now, they're still the most common way to pass messages between view controllers.